# Database Management using Python

Tags: python, database, database-backups

I want to create a SQLite3 database using python and wanted to know what is the best method of managing it? When I say managing, I mean how to ensure that there is a backup if/when there is some kind of corruption. Is there any way to retrieve it or is it better to have a backup of your whole database? What is a best practice?

TIA!

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. "create a database using python" could be anything from store some plain text files and read/manipulate in memory and save as plain text, to writing a SQL database, to the (more common and a lot easier) using MySQL, PostgreSQL or some other available database - which in turn can be on the same server or a separate server or a dedicated service such as AWS RDS. More context, size, project parameters needed to answer.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I am not sure about the server bit yet but I will be creating a SQLite3 database.

Comment: Start by reading up on SQLite3. It is a totally local, file based, system. You get (within reason) the advantages of SQL as far as query language, table structures, etc. but without having to have a separate process or server to manage it.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thank you but my question is mostly with respect to the management of database. Irrespective of what database I create, what is the best method to have a backup to ensure you don't lose your data if the database gets corrupted?

Comment: Yes, that means two copies - fortunately, storage is cheap. But the details vary a LOT by system. If you are using MySQL or PostgreSQL in your own server, that typically means using mysqldump or similar to copy all the data in a controlled manner into a specific backup format. If you are using a remote service such as AWS RDS then it means "let someone else manage the backups and just set the timing and pay the bill". If you are using SQLite3 it means "copy the actual files".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thank you. Your answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, the database is currently planned to be SQLite3. That narrows down the scope considerably. Essentially, the database is, as far as operating system issues (processes, data file access, etc.) simply a file created and updated by the Python program directly. Which means any backup/restore is normally done by a full copy of the database file(s) to either another location on the same machine (handles corruption due to program problems but not hardware problems, OS crash, etc.) or over a network to either another local machine or a remote/cloud server of some sort.

If your application needs to run continuously, then you may want to manage backup *within* the application. If it runs periodically (specific times or via some external trigger) then you can have the backups run on a regular basis outside the application (which, for SQLite3, simply means a script to copy the appropriate file(s)).